# Tesseract: Getting word confidence (x_wconf) in hOCR file

Tags: java, ocr, tesseract

I am using Java currently to call Tesseract via commandline, the output mode is set to hOCR. I barely know anything of anything related to C programming, I can read the source code though, but that's about it.

I would like to be able to get the word confidence information in the hOCR files. I have found some "answers" on the net. Varying from setting a value in the settings file to changing and recompiling the source.

I am using the newest version of Tesseract, how will I get the word confidence (x_wconf) from within Java?

Comment: Please edit your question adding what you exactly want as in your comment from: Sep 25 at 9:24

Answer (score 0):

hOCR is HTML, so you'll need an HTML parser to extract the attribute you want. Try [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/), [HtmlCleaner](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/), or [HTML Parser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: The x_wconf value is not in the hOCR output in the newest Tesseract version (3.02), I did manage to install 3.01 yesterday though and found the value, but it seems of no use to my application.

Comment: I just verified the `x_wconf` values are there in hocr output by tesseract 3.02.03. Why is it of no use in your app?

Comment: Because it lists the confidence against the dictionary. And I was actually looking for the confidence against the visual representation of a character. As the confidence of handwriting should be low, and I wanted to filter out handwriting from invoices, such that they can be recognized.